# return link on web page in classic asp

Tags: asp.net

I have a "Go back to the previous page" link on my web page. I was using the following code to go to the previous page

```
 document.write('<a href="' + document.referrer + '"><span class="style2">Return to previous Page</span></a>');
```

If the page postback then the above code does not work so I am trying to the below code to go to the previous page, but this does not work properly either. 
Here is what I have

```
If InStr(LCase(Request.ServerVariables("http_referer")), "technicalinfo.aspx") > 0 Then
    Session("link") = "technicalInfo.aspx"
Else If InStr(LCase(Request.ServerVariables ("http_referer")), "Prodinfo.aspx") > 0 Then
    Session("link") = "ProdInfo.aspx"
End If
```

The error comes right here when I trying to redirect the user to a link that is provided by the session variable

```
<%dim URL as string =  Session("link")  %>
<a href=URL>Go Back to previous Page</a>
```

The above code does not work. How can I go back to the previous page based on the value from the Session variable?

Comment: Your idea won't work if the user's browser blocks the `Referer` header. If this is for a wizard-process then you should know what the Previous page is, otherwise what benefit does this link serve the user if they can just hit their browser's back button anyway?

Comment: I do know what my previous page is and that is why I am storing it in the session variable.

Comment: But why? What is the business case for this? How does it benefit the user or improve your application?

Comment: I just want to go to the previous page. Like you said that document.referrer  won't work then will be the alternative.

Comment: What should happen if a user accesses your webpage from a new window, where there is no previous or back page?

Comment: This is not an internet web site. Its intranet and user will whatever I will ask him to do,

Comment: Did you try History.go(-1) ?

Comment: Are you actually using classic ASP and not ASP.NET? Because your tag seems to indicate the opposite. There is a `classic-asp` tag.

Comment: You need to tell ASP that `URL` is a variable. So `<a href="<%=Session("link")%>">Go back to previous page</a>` (or something; it's been a large number of years since I've done classic ASP.

Comment: Oh, I was looking for asp tag. Thanks for letting me know. I will try the way you mentioned in your comment. I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You are best off using the client side [browser history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) to do this.

To implement a back button you would do something like this:

`<button onclick="window.history.back()">Back</button>`

Comment: This might not work in all cases, especially in classic ASP. The way it worked was to do a POST, followed by a GET, IIRC. So going back one in the history gets you to the POST request, not the previous GET.

Comment: Classic ASP is definitely a PITA. I don't think there is going to be a very generic solution to this problem. Will likely need to use a mix of browser history API, and `location.assign` / `location.replace` depending on if the browser history should be updated. When I had to do this recently, I threw the entire classic ASP application in an iframe and controlled it from the outside. Required wiring up code on the iframe load event to intercept all anchors and form submits as well as a handful of monkey patches to handle ajax etc.